# Power BI Pro and Premium per user license

Tags: powerbi

I am building reports in Power BI.

Can I buy premium per user license for developers and pro license for analysts. Would that work? Or should I buy premium per user license for all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed with Microsoft. Reports and dashboards in Premium workspaces can be shared with premium per user license users only and non-premium workspaces can be shared with pro license users within the same enviornment.

For example, if you need mulitple refreshes more than 8 (pro license limit), do the reloads in premium workspace and build the reports and dashboards in non-premium workspace. In this case, just the developer needs premium per user license and others just the pro license.

Answer (score 0):

it depends in how much you can invest and the atribuitions of each person, with pro account the developer can build and share the report using most of the visuals, functions....the premium have some specific and more robust functions in power bi desktop and power bi services.

try to look at the oficial princing site, it may help you take the decision:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/

Comment: I understand the difference in features. My question is can we mix premium per user license and pro license in the same enviornment? Or should everyone either have pro or premium per user license

Comment: yes, you can mix in the same environment.

Answer (score 0):

my dataset is in my premium workspace and my reports are in a non-premium workspace. But the user with the pro licence can't open the reports because of the missing premium license.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is wrong and misleading. Contents in pro workspace that use data from premium workspace can't be refreshed, you will have to refresh report in PBI Desktop and republish.